# Generate SQL Insert statements for SQLite with Django

Tags: django, sqlite, escaping, mysql-python

I want to generate a complete SQL file with Django that can be downloaded and executed to create a SQLite DB.

The problem is escaping the strings to insert them into the file to download. This is what I got so far:

```
name = MySQLdb.escape_string(self.name.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")
return "INSERT INTO names VALUES(%d,'%s');" % (self.id, name)
```

But unfortunately MySQL escapes single quotes with a backslash \ which SQlite does not like. I would prefer to use something contained in Django to replace MySQLdb.escape_string(). I'm not sure if there are any other issues of incompatibility between MySQL-escaping and SQLite therefore it would be good to avoid MySQLdb.escape_string() completely.

As a last recourse I would do this before returning:

```
name = name.replace("\\\'","\'\'")
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has the `quote` function for this.
It's also used by the `sqlite3` command-line tool when you `.dump` an entire database.

Comment: I can't find any reference to using this function from within Python/Django http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: It's an *SQLite* function. You can use it only if your original data is in a database.

Comment: The original data is in a MySQL Database, but I don't want to work on the DB level. I use a Django view to generate the file for download.